# Python PyQt5 QToolTip doesn't show the tip when cursor on the button

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4, pyqt5

I want to show a tip when cursor on a specific button. Here is my code;

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont    
import sys

class YeniPencere(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(800,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Title")

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')
        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50) 

uygulama = QApplication(sys.argv)
pencere = YeniPencere()
pencere.show()
uygulama.exec_()
```

Program running without any problem, but when I move my cursor on the button there is no tip. Nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Comment: on linux (manjaro) your code works as expected. both tooltips are shown, if uygulama is the active window as written here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop

Comment: @a_manthey_67 not working on windows 7, don't know why.

Comment: on my windows 7 its working correctly, the issue must be outside of your code. Are you running the code you've posted?

Comment: @a_manthey_67 No I'm not running the code I posted, I run another code and I'm asking the question with these codes. For god sakes of course I'm running the codes I've posted.